# Series with different time ranges in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use plot a line chart with multiple (3 to 5) series. Each of them covers a period that may or not cross (overlap) another line.

http://jsfiddle.net/MicheleC/E4SnM/

I tried to define each series via array of [x,y] like

```
"series": [
 {
"data": [
 [
 new Date(2004,0,30),
  8175 
],
[
 new Date(2004,9,1),
  8367 
],
....
```

But `highcharts` converts dates in numbers and make each series to start from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell highcharts that the xAxis is a date. It defaults to linear.

```
            "xAxis": {
                "type": "datetime",
            "title": {
                "text": "DATE"
            }
```

You then need to probably format your xAxis labels as well to how you want them to show.

Comment: thanks, I'm managing to format the xAxis to display what I need. The main problem seems that it still makes each series to start from the first point.

Comment: What do you mean "start from the first point"? How else would a series start?

Comment: from http://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-irregular-time t seems I need to use, say, `Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27)` instead of `new Date(1970,9,27)`.

Comment: Correct. You send in the time stamp as js time. `Date.UTC()` is the most common way to do this.

Comment: I mean that one line start from e.g. 2010-10-10 and ends 2011-01-01, then another line would start e.g. from 2011-01-01 and ends 2012-01-01. But, if you look at the my example, all the lines start from the "first point on the left"